# Using visudo to edit sudoers on Mac

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, sudo

I have somehow managed to make the sudoers file on my Mac error:

```
    $ sudo visudo
    >>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 45 <<<
    sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 45
    sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
```

So, I went and got the standard `sudoers` file [from here](http://opensource.apple.com/source/sudo/sudo-60/src/sudoers), logged in as root and copied it from Documents to `/etc`, but that didn't solve the problem.

If I try to run `visudo` using root it fires up Sublime Text and I see a blank `sudoers.tmp` which I understand is the lock file.

If I try and copy the contents of the downloaded `sudoers` file into `sudoers.tmp` using Sublime I get the above error.

So, does anyone have a solution to this?
What should I see when I run the 'visudo' command, Sublime Text and sudoers.tmp?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your `visudo` does not work as expected, maybe because your editor does not work correctly, try setting the the `EDITOR` environment variable to a sane value, then launching `visudo`:

```
EDITOR=nano visudo
```

This will work for `sh`, `bash`, `dash`, and other compatible shells.

Comment: Works for `zsh` also. Note that `nano` will work, but it is actually `pico` that gets called as the editor.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue today, and was helped along by the information above, but I wanted to keep my editor set to Sublime for other purposes.  I added the following to my `~/.bash_profile`, which solves the `visudo` issue, but doesn't change my default editor for git, etc.

```
alias visudo='EDITOR=vi sudo visudo'
```

When executed, this changes the editor to `vi` for the command that follows, and lets you edit the `sudoers` file successfully.

Answer (score -2):

If you've got a recent version of macOS (e.g. Ventura), you'll find that Apple has done something different wrt `visudo`. You can still change it to whatever you'd like, but you should do this in the `Defaults` section of the `/etc/sudoers` file.

In my version of Ventura, the `Default` was set as follows:

```
Defaults        env_keep += "EDITOR VISUAL"
```

This is exactly the same setting as in my older Catalina system, but it seems that neither of the environment variables "EDITOR -or-VISUAL" is defined in Ventura. Perhaps the simplest thing is to simply edit the `/etc/sudoers` file to add the following line to reflect your choice as editor; ***for example***:

If you run MacPorts, and have an updated version of `nano`:

```
Defaults        editor=/opt/local/bin/nano
```

or, if you use the "stock" `nano` that comes with most versions of macOS:

```
Defaults        editor=/usr/bin/nano
```

<sub>* which actually now points to `pico` :P</sub>

Comment: These are two different variables, and you can easily set either of them in your shell (which is useful for other things beside `visudo`. Also, the `env_keep` variable is used to define env variables `sudo` does not strip from the environment before running the command, so your new version does something completely different.

Comment: @nohillside: Your comment is unclear: "your new version does something completely different."  And yes, you could set this from the shell, but then it would apply to everything - not just `visudo`. But thanks for the downvote - encouragement is always welcome.

Comment: `sudo` and `/etc/sudoers` haven't changed with Ventura (at least regarding the problem the OP had in 2014), and neither `EDITOR` nor `VISUAL` are set by default (in any shell).  Also, `env_keep += ...` just defines env variables which get passed through to the command called via `sudo`, it does not *set* an editor (most likely, the OP had `EDITOR` set to `subw` which doesn't work via `sudo`).

Comment: Your modification changes the editor used by `visudo` for everybody on the system (which on most Macs isn't an issue, but might be on systems with several users). It also depends on `nano` being installed by the user (so if there is no `nano` in the location specified, calling `visudo` will fail (`visudo: specified editor (xxxx) doesn't exist`), something which is difficult to resolve. If you want to use a different editor just for `visudo`, set and export `SUDO_EDITOR` in your shell.

Comment: @nohillside: It seems like most of your comment relates to knowing whether or not `nano` has been installed... that's a bit of a stretch - even for you. Wrt the remainder of your comment, being able to set `SUDO_EDITOR` works if you **always use the same shell**... but what if someone uses several different shells, but always wants to use the same editor for for `sudoers` file? Your answer would seem to be that you set the environment variable **N** times; once for each shell??

Comment: I can't speak for others, but personally I define the environment for all shells I regularly use. Please also keep in mind that over time a lot of people will read this answer, and not all of them will know that there is no `/opt/local/bin/nano` by default.

Comment: @nohillside: Well, by all means, let's judge all answers by what you *regularly do*. Your reasoning is weak; your comment and downvote were petty and biased.